# How to use DynamoDBStreamEvent Trigger Lambda when only update certain attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I use serverless framework to deploy cloudFormation.
I want to trigger lambda to deleteObject on my S3 bucket after I update my DynamoDB Table with certain attribute, eg. my table has account, user, icon, I only want when I update icon, it trigger Lambda to delete my iconObject on S3 bucket.

As I read the documentation on AWS, it seems the eventName of dynamoDB stream Event only have three status, REMOVE, MODIFY, INSERT.

[AWS Documentation » Amazon DynamoDB » API Reference » Data Types » Amazon DynamoDB Streams » Record
Record](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html)

Could I do as below? But how do I know it update icon instead other attribute like account or user?

```
if (this._record.eventName === 'MODIFY' && this._record.NewImage!== this._record.OldImage ){
        return this._remove(this._record.dynamodb);
    }
```

Comment: Hi, can you have a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020731/lambda-runs-multiple-times-with-dynamodb-trigger

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are on the right track. If the DynamoDB StreamViewType is set to `NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES` then when `record.eventName === 'MODIFY'`, `record.dynamodb.NewImage` will contain the updated version of the item and `record.dynamodb.OldImage` will contain what the item was before the update. You could then inspect the 2 objects and look for changes in the fields you are interested in.

Comment: Ah!!!!!! Thanks @bwinant! Had a hard time figuring out what's NewImage and OldImage.

Comment: Hi, can you have a look here please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70020731/lambda-runs-multiple-times-with-dynamodb-trigger